# How to assing a custom method inside a @selector XCode5

Tags: macos, xcode5, selector, nsalert

I have a NSAlert in XCode5

```
NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];

    [alert setMessageText:@"Notificación"];
    [alert setInformativeText:mensaje];
    [alert setAlertStyle:NSInformationalAlertStyle];
    [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:window modalDelegate:nil
                     didEndSelector:@selector(myMethod})
                        contextInfo:nil];
```

as you see on didEndSelector I have a section for adding a method, is it possible to create there inside a custom method for making just an action, for instance something like this

```
[alert beginSheetModalForWindow:window modalDelegate:nil
                     didEndSelector:@selector(myCustomMethod{NSLog(@"hola");})
                        contextInfo:nil];
```

this is for saving the time of adding tons of methods one for each NSAlert

thanks in advance for the support

Answer (score 0):

create separated method with some NSLOG for example

```
- (void)logs {
   NSLog(@"lalalalalal")
}
```

Then send it to selector:

```
@selector(logs)
```

If your method receiving some variable, your select should be like:

```
@selector(logs:)
```

Comment: what I want is to avoid separate method creation, because I have a lot of NSAlerts there, so I want to declarate the method there inside of each NSAlert, is there a way to do that??